# How to select unlink image and delete items from multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, join, mysql-8.0

I am trying to delete category with items in it.

I have 4 tables :

**categories**

catId

**posts**

post_id

**images**

image_post_id

**tags**

tag_post_id

My sql query is like this for select and unlink images :

```
SELECT * FROM categories, posts, images, comments, tags 
WHERE catId = 25 
AND post_catId = catId 
AND image_post_id = post_id 
AND comment_post_id = post_id 
AND tag_cat_id = catId 
AND tag_post_id = post_id
```

but it doesnt show posts, category has over 100 posts in it.

when I search only in category and posts it displays all.

Comment: `FROM categories, posts, images, comments, tags` I believe this a cross join in MySQL

Comment: Do not write joins like that. Use proper `join` syntax with `on` criteria for how the join relates. The `where` should be for what to return, not join relation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using INNER JOIN, with it you will get results when related records are found in all 4 tables. You need to use LEFT JOIN, similar to this:

```
SELECT * FROM categories
 LEFT JOIN posts on post_catId = catId
 LEFT JOIN images ON image_post_id = post_id 
 LEFT JOIN comments ON comment_post_id = post_id 
 LEFT JOIN tags ON tag_cat_id = catId AND tag_post_id = post_id
  WHERE catId = 25;
```

Then you will see all data related to your catid=25.

Comment: I should use table name as alias, no left need join https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html thanks anyway.

Comment: Alias is NOT mandatory, you can use alias (or table name directly with dot notation) if your join condition includes columns having same names.